# Ruby on rails cant get values from textfield to array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, textfield, form-for

I need to get an array of strings from **f.text_field** and store it into a database.

```
  <div>
    <%= f.label :name %>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>

  <div>
    <%= f.label :tags %>
    <%= f.text_field :tags%>
  </div>
```

`tags` is an attribute and it is in an array. Name stores into the database correctly but nothing to tags.

How can i do this?
Thanks

Comment: We need a bit more info, what does your controller code look like, model?

Comment: In model are only assotiations and nothing helpfull to slove this. In controller is only def index, new, create, edit and update

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably want to either parse that on the client side with JS to create an array that gets stored in a hidden field, or something similar. Alternatively, you should pass the raw text to the controller and parse it ruby. You should probably do the latter as you will probably want to sanitize the input.

Answer (score 0):

There is a very good gem available for handling tagging. It's called acts-as-taggable and is found here https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on